# Problem Installing Boost.Python: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration

Tags: linux, boost

I'm trying to install Python.Boost on Linux. I extracted the .tar.bz2 to /usr/local, bootstrap was successful, but trying to do `./b2 --with-python` results in the following error message:

```
warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration note: failed. See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets ...found 1 target... ...updating 1 target... config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam /bin/sh: 2: cannot create bin.v2/project-cache.jam: Permission denied

warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam
/bin/sh: 2: cannot create bin.v2/project-cache.jam: Permission denied

    cat "/tmp/jamace8d64e.000" > "bin.v2/project-cache.jam"

...failed config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam...
...failed config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam...
```

Any insight will be appreciated.

Tried: configuring the user-config.jam file, providing the direct path via ./b2 --with-python=path/to/python3 via which python3.

Expected: Boost.Python will install successfully.

Actual Result: the above mentioned error message.

Answer (score -1):

create soft link python3* to python

Comment: To use answer area,  it is not sufficient. Please use comment area for short feedback and answers.

Comment: Answers are not measured by their length. If this is the right procedure to fix the issue, then it is an answer, even if it could be improved.